# Reuse Fastlane match for encrypting other credentials and android key stores

Tags: git, encryption, fastlane, fastlane-match

I'm using Fastlane match to manage my code signing of iOS.

Is there a way to use the same repo for storing other project credentials [keys, API tokens, etc] which are used in the app but cannot be checked in Git, or use Fastlane match commands to create a new encrypted repo?

***The below code executes but the file in the repo out.txt isn't encrypted.***

**Current code:**

```
  desc "Encrypt git"
  lane :encrypt do  
    UI.success "Encrypting git!"
    storage = Match::Storage.for_mode("git", { git_url: git_url, shallow_clone: shallow_clone, git_branch: branch, clone_branch_directly: true})  
    storage.download
    encryption = Match::Encryption.for_storage_mode("git", { git_url: git_url, working_directory: storage.working_directory})
    encryption.decrypt_files
    file = "#{storage.working_directory}/out.txt"
    out_file = File.new("#{file}", "w")
    out_file.puts("version:#{Time.now.to_i}")
    out_file.close 
    encryption.encrypt_files
    files_to_commit = Dir[File.join(storage.working_directory, "**", "*.{txt}")]
    encryption.encrypt_files
    storage.save_changes!(files_to_commit: files_to_commit)
  end 
end
```

**Output:**

```
Successfully loaded Appfile at path '/Users/xx/Workspace/yy/ci/zz/fastlane/Appfile'
-------
Successfully loaded Appfile at path '/Users/xx/Workspace/yy/ci/zz/fastlane/Appfile'
-------
WARN [2019-05-31 03:15:16.70]: You have required a gem, if this is a third party gem, please use `fastlane_require 'match'` to ensure the gem is installed locally.
INFO [2019-05-31 03:15:17.00]: ------------------------------
INFO [2019-05-31 03:15:17.00]: --- Step: default_platform ---
INFO [2019-05-31 03:15:17.00]: ------------------------------
INFO [2019-05-31 03:15:17.01]: Driving the lane 'mac test' 
INFO [2019-05-31 03:15:17.01]: Encrypting git!
INFO [2019-05-31 03:15:17.01]: Cloning remote git repo...
INFO [2019-05-31 03:15:17.01]: $ git clone ./../gitrepo/.git /var/folders/7s/s7248n8j0yz0lth821hx4bdm0000gp/T/d20190531-95641-60lael -b master --single-branch
INFO [2019-05-31 03:15:17.02]: ▸ Cloning into '/var/folders/7s/s7248n8j0yz0lth821hx4bdm0000gp/T/d20190531-95641-60lael'...
INFO [2019-05-31 03:15:17.13]: ▸ done.
INFO [2019-05-31 03:15:17.15]:   Successfully decrypted certificates repo
INFO [2019-05-31 03:15:17.15]:   Successfully encrypted certificates repo
INFO [2019-05-31 03:15:17.15]: Pushing changes to remote git repo...
INFO [2019-05-31 03:15:17.15]: $ git add /var/folders/7s/s7248n8j0yz0lth821hx4bdm0000gp/T/d20190531-95641-60lael/match_version.txt
INFO [2019-05-31 03:15:17.17]: $ git add /var/folders/7s/s7248n8j0yz0lth821hx4bdm0000gp/T/d20190531-95641-60lael/out.txt
INFO [2019-05-31 03:15:17.19]: $ git commit -m \[fastlane\]\ Updated\ \ and\ platform\ 
INFO [2019-05-31 03:15:17.24]: ▸ [master 6bdc078] [fastlane] Updated  and platform
INFO [2019-05-31 03:15:17.25]: ▸ 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
INFO [2019-05-31 03:15:17.25]: $ git push origin master
INFO [2019-05-31 03:15:17.31]: ▸ Enumerating objects: 5, done.
INFO [2019-05-31 03:15:17.31]: ▸ Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
INFO [2019-05-31 03:15:17.31]: ▸ Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
INFO [2019-05-31 03:15:17.31]: ▸ Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
INFO [2019-05-31 03:15:17.32]: ▸ Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 289 bytes | 144.00 KiB/s, done.
INFO [2019-05-31 03:15:17.32]: ▸ Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
INFO [2019-05-31 03:15:17.37]: ▸ To /Users/xx/Workspace/yy/ci/zz/fastlane/./../gitrepo/.git
INFO [2019-05-31 03:15:17.37]: ▸ cac225c..6bdc078  master -> master
INFO [2019-05-31 03:15:17.37]: Finished uploading files to Git Repo [./../gitrepo/.git]
INFO [2019-05-31 03:15:17.44]: Successfully generated documentation at path '/Users/xx/Workspace/yy/ci/zz/fastlane/README.md'

+------+------------------+-------------+
|           fastlane summary            |
+------+------------------+-------------+
| Step | Action           | Time (in s) |
+------+------------------+-------------+
| 1    | default_platform | 0           |
+------+------------------+-------------+

INFO [2019-05-31 03:15:17.45]: fastlane.tools finished successfully
```

Comment: What does "other project credentials" refer to?

Comment: And more important: How do you want to use those credentials and other information you put into that repo?

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.fastlane.tools/advanced/other/#manually-manage-the-fastlane-match-repo (Click on `Instructions` to see the actual content) has advice on how you can manually decrypt and encrypt data from the match repository.

This could potentially be used to place all kinds of data in there. As the code is just plain ruby, you can of course also include that in any script or program you write to automate the process (instead of doing it manually in `irb` as in the instructions.